# Triggering Windows "Open With" popup with "Always use this app" option

Tags: windows

I'm using the Windows `OpenWith.exe` to trigger the Open With-popup in a desktop application. However, this differs from the one triggered via Windows Explorer (file context menu -> Open With -> Choose Another App) so that it lacks the "Always use this app to open .xyz files." option. Is it possible to make this option appear somehow?